How to loop through an array of strings using pointers
I have been learning C for the past month and I can't get past my current problem.
I have an array of strings pointer:
char **symbols;       // An array of stock symbols for the set name

I load the array using the following function:
/*
    get_symbols - 11/02/2024
    Retrieves the symbols for the set list from the database
*/
void get_symbols(void)
{
    char *sql = concatenate(sql1, set_name, sql2);
       
    PGresult *r1 = PQexec(conn, sql);

    if (PQresultStatus(r1) != PGRES_TUPLES_OK) {

        printf("No data retrieved\n");
        PQclear(r1);
        db_exit(conn);
    }

    symbol_count = PQntuples(r1);
    symbols = malloc(symbol_count * sizeof(char*));
    if (symbols == NULL)
    {
        puts("Malloc error for symbols");
        exit(2);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < symbol_count; i++)
        *(symbols+i) = PQgetvalue(r1, i, 0);

    free(sql);
    PQclear(r1);
}

I can loop through the array and print each symbol to the screen correctly:
/* Process each symbol */
for(int i = 0; i < symbol_count; i++)
{
    /* Get the stock data */
    // get_stock_data(*(symbols+i));
    printf("%s\n", *(symbols+i));
}


But then I try to load the data for each stock symbol and display it:
/* Process each symbol */
for(int i = 0; i < symbol_count; i++)
{
    /* Get the stock data */
    get_stock_data(*(symbols+i));
}

The get_stock_data is the function called to retrieve and display the data:
/*
    get_stock_data - 11/04/2024
    Gets the stock data from the database for a given symbol and fills the
    stock_data linked list.
*/
void get_stock_data(char *symbol)
{
    char *sql = concat(sql3, symbol, sql4, begin_date, sql5, end_date, sql6);
    
    PGresult *r2 = PQexec(conn, sql);

    if (PQresultStatus(r2) != PGRES_TUPLES_OK)
    {
        printf("No data retrieved\n");
        PQclear(r2);
        return;
    }

    int data_count = PQntuples(r2);
    printf("%d\n", data_count);
    for(int row = 0; row < data_count; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < 7; col++)
            printf("%s  ", PQgetvalue(r2, row, col));
        putchar('\n');
    }

    free(sql);
    PQclear(r2);
}

The first symbol displays correctly and sometimes the 2nd symbol is passed-in correctly but then the symbols are incorrect looking like garbage characters:

I have tried everything I can think of but I haven't been able to correct the issue.  Do you see anything wrong with my code?  Thank you in advance!

please read, "how to ask?", here on SO. it will be better if you had replaced images with a text.

Please note that for any pointer or array p and index i, the expression *(p + i) is exactly equal to p[i]. The latter, using array indexing, is usually much easier to read and understand (and less to write).

And please try to create a single and coherent [mre] to show us.

Your problem is most likely that the value you got from PQgetvalue self-destructs when PQclear is called and is no longer there when you look at it. Try copying it with strdup or something. See also PQgetvalue documentation

PQgetvalue Returns the field (attribute) value... The value returned by PQgetvalue points to storage that is part of the PGresult structure. One must explicitly copy the value into other storage if it is to be used past the lifetime of the PGresult structure itself.
From here: <https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/libpq-exec.html>

Please check if this is something that's applies to your code?

It doesn't look like the code is using the value beyond printing it once though? So how can that be the bug?

Obviously get_stock_data(*(symbols+i)); printf("%s\n", *(symbols+i)); with both lines uncommented will not work.

I was pointing to the get_symbols function which populates the symbols table with pointers that are no longer valid on leaving the function.

@teapot418 That fixed the problem.  Thank you!

Please create an answer according to [answer] or delete this question.
